# Can't render list of object between two dates in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to render list of concerts between two dates. Problem is that user need to first select desired dates on the page before whole filtering function can run. There is only one `useEffect` inside the component and I can't filter there because `start date` and `end date` are required to this to work.
So I moved my filtering function outside the `useEffect` and now i am getting infinite loop. How to solve that problem in best and professional way ?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Explore = () => {
  //Raw JSON Date example:  "2023-02-08T23:15:30.000Z"
  let currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);

  const [concerts, setConcerts] = useState([]);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(currentDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(currentDate);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(25);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadConcerts = async () => {
      const request = await axios.get("data/concerts");
      setConcerts(request.data);
    };
    loadConcerts();
  }, []);

  const filtered = concerts.filter((concert) => {
    return concert.datum >= startDate && concert.datum <= endDate;
  });

  setConcerts(filtered);

  if (!filtered.length) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label for="start">Start date:</label>
      <label for="end">End date:</label>

      <input
        type="date"
        id="start"
        value={startDate}
        min="2023-01-01"
        max="2030-12-31"
        onChange={(event) => setStartDate(event.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="date"
        id="end"
        value={endDate}
        min="2023-01-01"
        max="2030-12-31"
        onChange={(event) => setEndDate(event.target.value)}
      />

      <div>
        */ <Rendering concert cards> */
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Explore;
```

Comment: You can simply use `filtered` to render your items. No need to `setConcerts` with the `filtered` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another `useEffect` triggered when the `startDate` or `endDate` gets changed

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Explore = () => {
  //Raw JSON Date example:  "2023-02-08T23:15:30.000Z"
  let currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);

  const [concerts, setConcerts] = useState([]);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(currentDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(currentDate);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(25);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadConcerts = async () => {
      const request = await axios.get("data/concerts");
      setConcerts(request.data);
    };
    loadConcerts();
  }, []);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const filtered = concerts.filter((concert) => {
        return concert.datum >= startDate && concert.datum <= endDate;
      });
    
      setConcerts(filtered);
  },[startDate,endDate])
  

  if (!filtered.length) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label for="start">Start date:</label>
      <label for="end">End date:</label>

      <input
        type="date"
        id="start"
        value={startDate}
        min="2023-01-01"
        max="2030-12-31"
        onChange={(event) => setStartDate(event.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="date"
        id="end"
        value={endDate}
        min="2023-01-01"
        max="2030-12-31"
        onChange={(event) => setEndDate(event.target.value)}
      />

      <div>
        */ <Rendering concert cards> */
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Explore;
```

Comment: Thanks looks like it solved my question. I just have another problem but its for another topic.

Comment: sure, since keep `useEffect` runs at the intiial render so keep a note of that until user selects proper date range..